# Docker private registry as kubernetes pod - deleted images auto-recreated

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, images, docker-registry

I run a docker private registry v2.7.0 as a [kubernetes pod with a service and a persistent volume, thanks to the Varun Kumar G tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/deploy-your-private-docker-registry-as-a-pod-in-kubernetes-f6a489bf0180), which has been the only successful method on my setup, for kubernetes to pull from my private docker registry on my **3 node--on-premises--cluster with ubuntu 20.04 lts kvms**.

The problem is with deleting images from the kubernetes pod docker registry v2.7.0 ([had to use the previous version because latest v2.7.1 does not work with htpasswd](https://github.com/docker/distribution-library-image/issues/106)). Furthermore I have read lots of similar threads like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/905065/docker-private-registry-deleted-all-images-but-still-showing-in-catalog), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436742/how-to-delete-images-from-a-private-docker-registry) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802202/docker-registry-2-0-how-to-delete-unused-images).

With docker registry v2.7.1 run **as a docker container**, I had no problems deleting images,

but with docker registry v2.7.0 run **as a kubernetes pod**, the usual deletion steps **result being unable to push the deleted image again**, even **after successfully deleting blobs and manually deleting image folders** under `/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/`.

Below is the registry pod yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dockreg-pod
  labels:
    app: mregistry
spec:
  containers:
  - name: registry
    image: registry:2.7.0
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    volumeMounts:
    - name: repo-vol
      mountPath: "/var/lib/registry"
    - name: certs-vol
      mountPath: "/certs"
      readOnly: true
    - name: auth-vol
      mountPath: "/auth"
      readOnly: true
    env:
    - name: REGISTRY_AUTH
      value: "htpasswd"
    - name: REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM
      value: "Registry Realm"
    - name: REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH
      value: "/auth/htpasswd"
    - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE
      value: "/certs/tls.crt"
    - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY
      value: "/certs/tls.key"
    - name: REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED
      value: "true"
  volumes:
  - name: repo-vol
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: repo-pvc
  - name: certs-vol
    secret:
      secretName: certs-secret
  - name: auth-vol
    secret:
      secretName: auth-secret
  restartPolicy: Always
  nodeName: spring
```

and following is the persistent volume yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: repo-pv
  labels:
    type: prstore
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 7Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    fsType: ext4
    path: /root/repo
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - spring
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: repo-pvc
  labels:
    type: prstore
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      type: prstore
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 7Gi
```

Say I am pushing an image on a brand new registry pod having also wiped out the persistent storage beforehand.

```
root@sea:scripts# docker push dockreg:5000/mubu4:v4
The push refers to repository [dockreg:5000/mubu4]
9f54eef41275: Pushed 
v4: digest: sha256:7bd0d9a9821815dccb5c53c18cea04591ec633e2e529c5cdd39681169589c17f size: 529
```

Deletion of images appears to work as intended until I try to push the deleted image again, at which point I am getting the dreaded `Layer already exists` error.

As you might have seen above, I have included in the registry pod environment the following,

```
- name: REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED
      value: "true"
```

otherwise I would get an `unsupported` error from the `curl -X DELETE` call, even after adding

```
delete:
    enabled: true
```

in the `/etc/docker/registry/config.yml` within the pod,

```
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
  delete:
    enabled: true
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
```

that seems to make no difference in my use case.

Following are the [deletion steps](https://gist.github.com/jaytaylor/86d5efaddda926a25fa68c263830dac1).

```
curl -u alexander:sofianos \
> -vsk -H "Accept: \
> application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
> -X DELETE \
> https://dockreg:5000/v2/mubu4/manifests/sha256:\
> 7bd0d9a9821815dccb5c53c18cea04591ec633e2e529c5cdd39681169589c17f
```

The above prints among other things the following

```
> DELETE /v2/mubu4/manifests/sha256:7bd0d9a9821815dccb5c53c18cea04591ec633e2e529c5cdd39681169589c17f HTTP/2
> Host: dockreg:5000
> authorization: Basic YWxleGFuZGVyOnNvZmlhbm9z
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 250)!
< HTTP/2 202 
< docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< content-length: 0
< date: Sat, 30 Oct 2021 13:25:53 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host dockreg left intact
```

which seems to be in order.

Below, deleting blobs from within the registry pod

```
root@sea:scripts# kubectl exec -it dockreg-pod -- sh
/ # bin/registry garbage-collect  /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
mubu4

0 blobs marked, 3 blobs and 0 manifests eligible for deletion
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:7b1a6ab2e44dbac178598dabe7cff59bd67233dba0b27e4fbd1f9d4b3c877a54
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/7b/7b1a6ab2e44dbac178598dabe7cff59bd67233dba0b27e4fbd1f9d4b3c877a54  go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=82a101ee-47f4-4f4f-bc79-76d774b0924b service=registry
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:7bd0d9a9821815dccb5c53c18cea04591ec633e2e529c5cdd39681169589c17f
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/7b/7bd0d9a9821815dccb5c53c18cea04591ec633e2e529c5cdd39681169589c17f  go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=82a101ee-47f4-4f4f-bc79-76d774b0924b service=registry
blob eligible for deletion: sha256:ecb35fc8715f5ab1d9053ecb2f2d9ebbec4a59c0a0615d98de53bc29f7285085
INFO[0000] Deleting blob: /docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/ec/ecb35fc8715f5ab1d9053ecb2f2d9ebbec4a59c0a0615d98de53bc29f7285085  go.version=go1.11.2 instance.id=82a101ee-47f4-4f4f-bc79-76d774b0924b service=registry
```

Lastly, manually deleting the repository image

```
/ # rm -rf /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/mubu4
```

On my persistent storage, the registry now looks like this

```
root@spring:repo# tree
.
└── docker
    └── registry
        └── v2
            ├── blobs
            │   └── sha256
            │       ├── 7b
            │       └── ec
            └── repositories

8 directories, 0 files
```

But when I try to push the deleted image again, I get

```
root@sea:scripts# docker push dockreg:5000/mubu4:v4
The push refers to repository [dockreg:5000/mubu4]
9f54eef41275: Layer already exists 
v4: digest: sha256:7bd0d9a9821815dccb5c53c18cea04591ec633e2e529c5cdd39681169589c17f size: 529
```

and in my registry, **the mubu4 image folder I previously deleted, has been mystiriously recreated through the above push command**.

```
root@spring:repo# tree
.
└── docker
    └── registry
        └── v2
            ├── blobs
            │   └── sha256
            │       ├── 7b
            │       └── ec
            └── repositories
                └── mubu4
                    └── _manifests
                        ├── revisions
                        │   └── sha256
                        │       └── 7bd0d9a9821815dccb5c53c18cea04591ec633e2e529c5cdd39681169589c17f
                        │           └── link
                        └── tags
                            └── v4
                                ├── current
                                │   └── link
                                └── index
                                    └── sha256
                                        └── 7bd0d9a9821815dccb5c53c18cea04591ec633e2e529c5cdd39681169589c17f
                                            └── link

19 directories, 3 files
```

I also tried wiping out the persistent storage with

```
root@spring:repo# rm -rf *
```

to no avail. Trying to push the deleted image afterwards, still outputs the exact same `Layer already exists` error, and the registry tree is being again auto-recreated, looking exactly as it does in the above tree output.

**The question is** what else can I try to make this work, and/or alternatively,

it follows from the above testing, that **within the docker registry kubernetes pod, there are other files, that hold configuration where deleted images appear not to be deleted**, and these files activate the recreation of the deleted image through a docker push call. Where should I look apart from the tree

```
/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/
```

so I can delete all references to deleted images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is a caching issue at least with registry version 2.7.0 that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66440572/private-registry-not-working-properly-after-deleting-an-image) and [here](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/2094).

It is recommended in the above threads to disable cache completely or to restart the container every time.

Because I am using the docker registry as a kubernetes pod, changes to the default registry configuration file, ie. `/etc/docker/registry/config.yml` do not have any effect because the kubernetes registry pod yaml takes precedence, meaning the configuration has to be set in the pod yaml as environment variables in the form of `REGISTRY_variable` where the underscore represents indentation levels, as explained in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/).

So the solution is to add

```
- name: REGISTRY_STORAGE_CACHE_BLOBDESCRIPTOR
  value: ""
```

to the container environment in the pod yaml in order to disable cache completely, otherwise if the registry is run as a docker container we can use the following in the `config.yml`:

```
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: ""
```

The alternative is to restart the pod every time we delete an image with:

```
kubectl exec <pod_name> -c <container_name> -- reboot
```

or if it is a docker container

```
docker restart <registry_container>
```